# Get value of checked radio button

Tags: jquery, html

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radiobuttons" value="100">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radiobuttons" value="200">
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radiobuttons" value="300">


<div id="selectedvalue"></div>
```

How do I get value of the checked radio button and output it as text inside "selectedvalue" ? The function should take the value of the checked radio on pageload and on input change.

Comment: Google your title please

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //apply the value on page ready (you probably don't have to wait until everyithing loads - otherwise chage it to window.load()
    $('#selectedvalue').html( $('input[name=radiobuttons]:checked').val() );

    //bind the change event to update the element
    $('input[name=radiobuttons]').on('change', function () {
        $('#selectedvalue').html( $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You would do this by changing the text of your `selectedvalue` div.

Changing the `HTML` of your div may be unnecessary since you just want to display a number

```
$('#selectedvalue').text($('input[name=radiobuttons]:checked').val());
```

API -

- [.val()](http://$('input[name=radiobuttons]:checked').val())
- [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: This output the value on pageload and on input change ?

Comment: Just put it in a simple event then.